# CSS selector for other tags other than div and span?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, xml-namespaces, dd

I have been using css selectors as div and span till now while using Selenium WebDrivers with Ruby for testing.

However I have some dd and xmlns:dd attributes as well. Is it possible to have a css selector for this as well.

***Html Code:***

```
    <div class="class1 class2 class3 class4" style="padding: 4px;" id="_c04a6325-5316-4177-980f-38484eb27730"> 
      <span class="class5" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Month</span> 
        <div class="class6" dd:contenttype="Month" dd:referenceuuid="1446A201-FD91-4A82-B645-  306DC948DC48" id="_3d510b04-8a5a-4bf9-bc7a-8efd55f9ca48">
          <div xmlns:dd="Week" class="class7 class8" dd:entityid="1457893" dd:contenttype="Monday" id="_7480bbe4-bbf0-4a54-8994-ae773b418470">
             Breakfast 
          </div> 
        </div>
      </span>
   </div>
```

***What I presently do:***

```
$driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.class7.class8')
```

***What I want to do:***

Something like this to use the data in dd:contenttype and/or xmlns:dd to find an element

```
$driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.dd:contenttype="Monday"')       OR
$driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.xmlns:dd="Week"')
```

Is the possible to find and element using dd:contenttype and/or xmlns:dd??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$driver.find_elements(:css, 'div[dd\\:contenttype="Monday"]')`

for more information you can take a look on http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/

Comment: I am getting some "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12" error is I try this way.

Comment: I went through the entire link and tried all the possible ways for 'dd:contenttype' tag but even this does not work for me.

Comment: I don't know if it is because the div is a nested div... But that shouldn't be the case with CSS selectors I guess. However I am updating the exact html code now with the nested div.

Comment: it doesn't matter that div is nested, you can verify that this selector work by executing: document.querySelector('div[dd\\:contenttype="Monday"]') in javascript  console

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//div[@class = 'class6 class7' and @dd:contenttype = 'Monday'")
```

The above should work.

Comment: I had tried the xpath method... Its not working for me so I went to use css. I just have one element with these attributes in the DOM, so I even tried doing find_element instead of find_elements and I am getting 'Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.' error.

Comment: I also tried removing the class attribute like: $driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@dd:contenttype = 'Monday']")

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the webpage link you are working on?

Comment: I am working on an desktop app which has part of html code or webview. So I doubt if it can be shared. But I have used the :xpath for other parts of app testing (which are not webview). For some reason its not working for any tags/attributes on webview.

Comment: One question - The attribute inside the div I am looking for is under a nested div. By that I mean <div class='Some class'> <span class='Some other class'> <div xmlns:dd="Week" class="ddemrcontentitem ddremovable" dd:entityid="1457893" dd:contenttype="Monday" id="_7480bbe4-bbf0-4a54-8994-ae773b418470">
     Breakfast 
</div> </span> </div>

Comment: Do I need to provide the entire nested path starting from the top outermost div then span and then the actual div??

Comment: I tried and it seems for some reason I guess the xpath thing itself is not working on my webview. I will have to figure out why. But Thanks for looking into my issue and replying me back!! :)